# lat and long with submit button

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-2

I'm and intern at an company that has asked me to put some markers on a google maps.
I did this with the lat and long since geocoding the addresses and than making markers out of that would take to long to load.

However, they now also asked if I could make an easy application to get the lat and long from addresses. So a simple geocoding app:

One input field and a submit button, when clicked on the button the lat and long will show up below or above or next to it.

Which function can i use to get this?

I've been looking on the internet for a few days now, but I can't find anything that also makes it so that i can show the lat and long that was found.

I'm not very good at programming.

Comment: All of your questions are very... similar.

Comment: this is another task :O others i'm not using lat and lng..
also using OSM there since the other task is larger and to big for the free google api

Comment: I see. Just be careful not to come across as asking "do my work for me", that's all.

Comment: na i also want to learn something from it :D

Comment: Did you look at the Google Maps API documentation? This is well documented.

Comment: i did yes got a few things from there to make the map however as i already mentioned i'm not that good at programming so it's rather hard :( this is just an task aside from my daily stuff since i'm not learning this at school however i've got some spare time today since my supervisor isn't here so i tried to get further however it's not easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im confused, are you trying to find the lat and lng of an address?

if so use google maps api
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

here is an example
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true

and that will spit back the lat and lng in a json format.

If you want to reverse geocode something
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true

To make an app that does it with a submit button, use jquery/ajax and pull the result from googles service.

Answer (score 2):

```
function get_tatitude_longitude(address){
var mygc = new google.maps.Geocoder();
mygc.geocode({'address' : address}, function(results, status){
    alert( "latitude : " + results[0].geometry.location.lat() );
    alert( "longitude : " + results[0].geometry.location.lng() );
 lat_c = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
long_c = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
mapa();
document.getElementById('lat').value = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
document.getElementById('long').value = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
document.getElementById('latlongclicked').value = marker.getPosition();

});

}
```

Comment: Can you add some context to your answer? What exactly is this code doing?

Comment: i have taken hidden input elements in my form and by inserting any address, if exists it's latitude and longitude get automatically inserted into hidden elements, if not then location entered in invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps given you experience you should try using [gmap3](http://gmap3.net/) for jQuery. It uses the Google Maps API v3, but abstracts the API making it a lot easier to use. They have an [example](http://gmap3.net/examples/address-lookup.html) you should study. It takes an address and returns a possible location.

Below I have modified the example which will alert the location – hopefully to giving you a head start:

```
$("#test").gmap3();

$('#address').autocomplete({
  //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
  source: function(request, response) {
    $("#test").gmap3({
      action:'getAddress',
      address: request.term,
      callback:function(results){
        if (!results) return;
        response($.map(results, function(item) {

          alert("The location is", item.geometry.location.lat(), item.geometry.location.lon());

          return {
            label:  item.formatted_address,
            value: item.formatted_address,
            latLng: item.geometry.location
          }
        }));
      }
    });
  },
  //This bit is executed upon selection of an address
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $("#test").gmap3(
      {action:'clear', name:'marker'},
      {action:'addMarker',
        latLng:ui.item.latLng,
        map:{center:true}
      }
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: how comes when i try to launch this script i get an empty page?

Comment: the script is given as an example demonstration of the __functions__ you can use to achieve what you want. that's all.